# Expected Classification error using indicator functions

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, classification, expected-value

I am given three variables (latter two are binary) $A,B$, and $C$, where $A$ = input vector, $B$ = whether data was chosen, and $C$ is the true label. $A$ and $B$ are conditionally independent given $C$

I have to prove this: ($\mathbb1$ is the indicator function)

$E_{(X,Y)\~D}[\mathbb1[f(a)\neq c]]$= $\int_{a} p(a,b=1)\mathbb1[f(a)\neq 1] + p(a,b=0)[p(c=1|a,b=0)\mathbb1[f(a)\neq1]+p(c=0|a,b=0)\mathbb1[f(a)\neq0]]dx$

Intuitively it kinda makes sense to me. The right-hand side is like the integral of the incorrect labels when the data is chosen plus the incorrect labels when the data is not chosen, but I have no idea how to begin to prove this. Any help would be great!